# Navigating through DataGrid using KeyBoard Arrows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, keyboard-shortcuts

I am working on WPF DataGrid. By Default DataGrid KeyBoard Shortcuts stuck when it gets into ComboBox (in Datagrid).

I have tried PreviewKeyDown, When i press arrow button it is not navigating within the DatagridCells instead it is coming from top/first UI element.

```
private void dataGrid1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Up));
                MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));
            }
            else if(e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Right));
            }
            else if(e.Key == Key.Left)
            {
                MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Left));
            }
}
```

I want to change this such that Right/Left shall navigate throughout the row and Up/Down shall navigate throughout the Datagrid Vertically.

Comment: If the focus is on Combobox the keys will behave as they behave in a combo box. I think you are trying to force it to move to next cell etc. when left/right key is pressed. If that's the case, my advice will be against it, as user can remove the focus and it will behave fine. However, in case you want to force it, handling Key events on Datagrid will not work, the focus is on Combo so handle Combo's Key event.